# Retain dynamic row with input when error occurs in validation

Tags: laravel

I have this table when page load.

```html
<table id="tableServices" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th style="width: 15%; text-align-last: right;"><a href="#" class="fa fa-plus" id="addRow"></a></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list_for_am">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" name="worker[]">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and add dynamic rows based on the user's preference using this code

```js
$('#addRow').on('click', () => {
    $('#list_for_am').append('<tr>' +
        '<td colspan="2"> ' +
        '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" name="worker[]">' +
        '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
    );
});
```

and from the controller, to validate if there are null value on one of the array elements I use this

```php
$request->validate([
    'schedule_date' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('schedules')->where(function ($query) use($data) {
            $query
                ->where('schedule_date', $data['schedule_date'])
                ->where('schedule_time', $data['schedule_time']);
        })
    ],
    'worker.*' => 'required'
]);
```

Now, if there are errors, the rows from the table is reset into only one row, not the total number of rows the user added previously. How to retain the number of rows and show the textbox where the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
@foreach( old('worker') as $item )
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" name="worker[]" value="{{ old('worker')[$loop->index] }}">
    </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. This one works. But if you don't mind, can i ask follow question, how can i make the input box with errors cover with border color red? I don't know what to condition in the style part.